# Creating new header child block in local.xml under <catalog_category_layered> doesn't work

Tags: blocks

I want to include my custom bolck inside `header` block, only on `<catalog_category_layered>`.

So I have this code in local.xml:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="header.catnav" as="header.catnav" template="catalog/catnav.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

And my block is not included. 
When I change my reference to `<reference name="head">` or `<reference name="left">` it gets included in these areas.

It doesn't get included in `name="content"` and `name="footer"` too.

What do you think am I doing wrong?
How do I make my block appear in the `header`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added `$this->getChildHtml('header.catnav')` to header's template?

Header block does not extend `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` block so `its children are not displayed automatically`. You need to call them in the template.

Comment: I forgot about it. That was exactly the problem. Dziekuje!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because the header block is different from the others.
the left block is a `core/text_list` type block. This means it displays all the child blocks, no questions asked.
The head block template contains `echo $this->getChildHtml()` that does the same thing...displays all the child blocks.

The header block has a separate template that does not call `getChildHtml()` without any parameters.
It just displays child blocks like this:

```
echo $this->getChildBlock('block_alias_here')
```

you need to add a similar line in `header.phtml` for your block `echo $this->getChildHtml('header.catnav')`

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer. Krzysztof was first so I'll accept his but thank you for taking time to write this!